# Best method to mark the numbers onto poker chips?

Tags: home-game

My personal set of poker chips is a typical cheap plastic set with solid colours.  I would like to mark numbers on them instead of memorising their values.

What is the best method of writing the numbers?  Has anyone tried this before?

Some options I thought of:

1. Permanent marker pen (would look sloppy as my handwriting isn't so neat)
2. Buy some stickers (might just fall off.  Is there a recommended brand of poker sticker?)
3. A stencil & spray paint

Comment: What if you want to play for different stakes next time?

Comment: I was thinking just numbers. 100 not $100. So wouldn't need to match 1 to 1 with stakes

Answer (score 3):

Rubber stamp. A few dollars each online. A variety of colors in the ink. Since you likely have a lot of chips to do, stamping is much faster and neater then compared to using a sharpey or stencil. This would be a good question at life hacks se and you would get a good response.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make a placard, similar to what you would find as a table setting card, and write the chip denominations there, in Sharpie on both sides of the card, and sit it on the table?

Such a placard is easily constructed by taping the tops together of two large index cards... or just fold a large piece of card stock or cardboard in half.

This way, you can later change the denominations easily, as you grow up in stakes.

[image]